# Generating model from existing database error in Symfony using Propel ORM

Tags: mysql, model, symfony-1.4, propel

i'm trying to generate a data model of a symfony project from a mysql database already existing. I'm using the Propel ORM to map that database into the config/schema.yml file using this command

```
php symfony propel:build-schema
```

and it works correctly. All tables in mySQL database has its own description in config/schema.yml file. The problem i when i try to generate the model classes with the command

```
php symfony propel:build-model
```

The execution of this command generates only 5 set of classes (BaseName, Name, NamePeer ...), when the shcema has about 40 tables.

How can i fix that?? maybe there is a configuration file with the maximum classes generated from the schema or something like that.

Thank you :D

edit:

the schema.yml auto generated from the database is like this (i can't post here the real generated schema because of the privacy of the code, i'm )

```
propel:
 _attributes:
   package: lib.model
   defaultIdMethod: native
table1:
 _attributes: { phpName: Table1 }
   TABLE_ID: { phpName: TableCod, type: INTEGER, size: '8', required: true, foreignTable: table1, foreignReference: TABLE_ID, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
   FOREIGN_KEY: { phpName: ForeignKey, type: INTEGER, size: '8', required: true, foreignTable: other_table, foreignReference: OTHER_TABLE_ID, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
   NORMAL_ATRIBUTE: { phpName: NormalAtribute, type: LONGVARCHAR, required: false }
 _indexes: { TABLE_ID: [TABLE_ID], FOREIGN_KEY: [OTHER_TABLE_ID] }
table2:

...
```

edit2:

I found the error, i didn't see it >_<

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size
>   of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tryed to
>   allocate 35 bytes) in
>   /usr/share/php/symfony/util/sfClassManipulator.class.php
>   on line 186

Comment: It would be helful if you could add the generated schema in your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by editting the php.ini file replacing the value of the script memory limit from -1 to 128. For some reason, symfony does not detect this parameter correctly (-1 means unlimited)